# Checking string in if statement

Tags: c++

Basically just trying to use == to check for a character

also im an idiot and i skipped a bunch of c++ classes and i have no idea how strings work as far as syntax goes, so any help there would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string letter;
    int number;

    letter = ' ';

    cout << "Please enter any ASCII letter" << endl;
    cin >> letter;


    if (letter == 'e')                       //Error is here
        {
            number = 1;
            cout << number << endl;
        }

    return 0;

}
```

I want to have the program check the letter and assign a number accordingly. I just made this simple script to test it, but I get error: no match for 'operator==' in 'letter == 'e''

Comment: C++ is not a scripting language...

Comment: Do you have a book? Then read it (from the beginning). Otherwise [get a couple of good ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: You define letter as string, and compare the string with a char. You cannot do that. You can compare e.g. letter[0] with 'e'.

Answer (score 1):

Because `'e'` is a char, not a string.
You defined `letter` as a string, so you can do one of the following:

1) define `letter` as char.

2) keep it as a string, and change `letter = ' ';` to `letter = " ";` and `if (letter == 'e')` to `if (letter == "e")`. (`""` represent a string, while `''` represent a char).

Answer (score 1):

in C, a string is an array of characters.
in C++, there is a standard library for it that extends the C definition.

in both C and C++, there is a difference between single and double quotes.
'd' means the character d and "d" means the string d.
so this seems like an invalid type error. if you choose to use the std::string type, then you can get the first character by array indexing [0].
but i was wondering why you didn't just do something like

```cpp
char letter = ' '
```